# Find quotient set cardinilty of $|\{0,1\}^A/R|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let A be finite set (not empty) and $B$ be subset of $A$

$fRg \iff ∀ x \in B : f(x) =g(x)$

($R$ Equivalence relation)

Any idea how to find $|\{0,1\}^A/R|$ when $B=\{\}$ and when $|B|=k$?

Comment: You should find a bijection between $\{0,1\}^A / R$ and $\{0,1\}^{B}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint** prove that the following function is a bijection:
$\varphi : \{0,1\}^A / R \to \{0,1\}^B $ such that
$$ \varphi([f]) = f_{|B} $$

1. $\varphi$ is well defined. If $f \sim g$, then $\forall x \in B \quad f(x) = g(x)$ which means that $f_{|B} = g_{|B}$ and so $\varphi([f]) = \varphi([g])$
2. $\varphi$ is iniective. $\varphi([f]) = \varphi([g]) \Rightarrow f_{|B} = g_{|B} \Rightarrow f \sim g \Rightarrow [f] = [g]$
3. $\varphi$ is suriective. Let $h: B \to  \{0,1\}$ and define
   $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
   0 & \textrm{if} \: x \in A \setminus B \\
   h(x) & \textrm{if} \: x \in B 
   \end{cases} $$
   Then $\varphi([f]) = f_{|B} = h$. So $\varphi$ is a bijection

Comment: i"ll be so thankful if you write the full proof

Comment: @J.Low.   He wrote out a very detailed proof.  If you are not willing to finish the last bit, then you need to reconsider if you should be taking a math course.

Comment: @WilliamElliot from the bijection we get that $|\{0,1\}^A/R|=|\{0,1\}^B|$,so when $B=\{\}$  $|\{0,1\}^A/R|=|\{0,1\}|^0=2^0=1$ and when $|B|=k$ $|\{0,1\}^A/R|=|\{0,1\}|^k=2^k$ , is that correct ?

Comment: yes, it is correct

Comment: @JayTuma thank you very much